# How to add multiple filters dynamically on an object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

This is the data I am attempting to filter:

```js
all_data = {
    'unique_identity1': {
        'name': 'abc ',
        'age': '22',
        'gender': 'M',
        'marks': '6'
    },
    'unique_identity2': {
        'name': 'xyz ',
        'age': '26',
        'gender': 'F',
        'marks': '2'
    },
    'unique_identity3': {
        'name': 'pqr ',
        'age': '65',
        'gender': 'M',
        'marks': '3'
    },
    // ...
}
```

These `unique_identity` and names are displayed on the UI. And 3 options `age`, `gender` and `marks` are given as filters. I want to filter `all_data` according to the given filter values like `age` from '10 to 40' or 'male' in `gender` or '2 to 6' in `marks`. A user can add multiple filters at a time and can remove them also. I am having problems in filtering the all_data according to the filters.

I have created an object called `filter_values`:

```
filter_values['age'] = "10-50"
```

So when any of the filters are added its key and values are added in this object. It goes to this method:

```js
function filter_samples(all_data, filter_values) {
    if (filter_values.hasOwnProperty('age')) {
       //check condition 
    }
    if (filter_values.hasOwnProperty('gender')) {
       //check condition 
    }
    if (filter_values.hasOwnProperty('marks')) {
        //check condition
    }
}
```

How do i add condition which is object of objects.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and very dirty solution with special format for search object, like that:

```
{ 
    gender: 'M',
    age: {
        min: 20, 
        max: 25
    }
}
```

```js
var data = {
        unique_identity1: { 'name': 'abc ', 'age': '22', 'gender': 'M', 'marks': '6' },
        unique_identity2: { 'name': 'xyz ', 'age': '26', 'gender': 'F', 'marks': '2' },
        unique_identity3: { 'name': 'pqr ', 'age': '65', 'gender': 'M', 'marks': '3' }
    };

function filter(object, search) {
    var r = {};
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        Object.keys(search).every(function (kk) {
            return (
                object[k][kk] === search[kk] ||
                typeof search[kk] === 'object' &&
                search[kk].min <= object[k][kk] &&
                object[k][kk] <= search[kk].max
            );
        }) && (r[k] = object[k]);
    });
    return r;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filter(data, { gender: 'M', age: { min: 20, max: 25 } }), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```